# Subdomain displays in Google in place of main domain

Tags: php, .htaccess, dns, seo

My main domain is polishwords.com.pl, but i noticed in Google some links are directed to:

mail.polishwords.com.pl

as you can see here:

[image: Subdomain not main domain]

I don't know whether it's PHP code or htaccess or DNS records. What can be the cause of this and how to fix it?

Comment: The cause is, unsurprisingly, that you are hosting content on that hostname.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is an SEO question without a programming component.

Comment: @Quentin No, i am hosting it on main domain, not on subdomains. What i want to know is how to fix it. It is a question involving htaccess, PHP and DNS, hence, it's a programming component. SEO has little to do this since server should not show content from main domain on subdomains. Thank you for support.

Comment: — Yes, you are. You can see it. http://mail.polishwords.com.pl/

Comment: @Quentin I don't feel like you know what you are talking about.

Comment: Ps. If you think it's offtopic for StackOverflow, what i think is wrong assumption, you should indicate what StackExchange property is best fitting for this question. Please act according to StackExchange rules.

Comment: @tomaszs I *know* what SO is for and the fact that 4 other developers found this to be off-topic speaks volumes. Neither myself or Quentin claimed to be awesome. Climb down off of that horse before you hurt yourself. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Jay Ok Jay, whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what can be the cause of this, but you can fix it with this `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^polishwords\.com\.pl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://polishwords.com.pl%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

That redirects all subdomains to the main domain

Comment: Hello. Thanks for answer. I've applied it the domain and it fixed the issue, but it occurred the issue is also on other domains. mail.domain.pl on most of my domains on my server point to polishwords.com.pl. So i think it will be  a DNS issue. But still your answer is valid for one domain so i vote it up. Thanks